# Que una ventana POPUP dure mas tiempo abierta

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

estoy haciendo un popup en wordpress sin plugins y tengo un problema y es que este se cierra de inmediato cuando necesito que se mantenga abierto al menos 10 segundos o mas, ademas de contar con un boton para cerrarlo, pero este ultimo vere la manera de integrarlo, ahora, lo importante es que no se usar, adjunto mi codigo JS, Functions, y HTML

```
window.addEventListener( 'load', function() {
    //Evento para abrir el pop up al pulsar un botón.            
    const btnAbrirPopup = document.querySelector( '#abrir-pop-up' );
        btnAbrirPopup.addEventListener( 'click', () => { 
        const popup = document.querySelector( '.soivigol-popup' );
        popup.classList.add( 'open' );
    });

    //Cerrar el pop up al pulsar en la aspa
    const btnClosePopup = document.querySelector( '.soivigol-close' );
    if ( btnClosePopup ) {
        btnClosePopup.addEventListener( 'click', () => {
        const popup = document.querySelector( '.soivigol-popup' );               
        popup.classList.remove( 'open' );
    });
}
});
```

```
function soivigol_insert_popup() {
    ?>
    <div class="soivigol-popup">
       <div class="soivigol-popup-inner">
                <?php if (have_posts()) : ?> <!-- Inicio del Loop -->
                <?php query_posts("category_name=integrantes"); ?> 
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 

                <img src="<?php the_field('imagen'); ?>" alt="">
                <span class="soivigol-close">&times;</span>

                <?php endwhile; ?> 
                <?php else : ?>  
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?> <!-- Fin del loop -->
       
       </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'soivigol_insert_popup' );
```

```
<td class="py-3"><a href="" class="btn btn-outline-warning" id="abrir-pop-up"><?php the_field('boton'); ?></td>


<div class="soivigol-popup">
    <div class="soivigol-popup-inner">
            

        <span class="soivigol-close">&times;</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Solo veo que abres el popup en tu código, pero no que lo cierres en ninguna parte. Tal como está ahora no tiene motivos para cerrarse solo.  ¿o falta código por alguna parte que no has puesto en la pregunta?

Comment: es cierto, editaré

Comment: Prueba cerrando el <a> que tienes en esta línea:  `<td class="py-3"><a href="" class="btn btn-outline-warning" id="abrir-pop-up"><?php the_field('boton'); ?></td>` pues quizás estás arrastrando ese link más abajo

Comment: Listo, ya esta solucionado, no era eso, sino que por alguna razon el codigo no funciona bien si se usa un <a>, tiene que ser un buttom

Comment: quizás con un `href="#"` lo hubieras solucionado, sino quizas te recargaba la propia página igualmente

Answer (score 0):

Podrías crear una función en javascript independiente, que es la que se encarga de llamar a tus clases, y dicha clase la envuelves dentro de un **setTimeout** y ya le añades los milisegundo que necesites Ejemplo :

```
window.setTimeout( TuFuncion , 10000);
```